# Banning user outside + inside server

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, converters

I'm trying my best to make a command that bans people inside and outside a server. Is this possible?

```
@client.command(aliases=["banmember", "banuser"])
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    if reason is None:
        reason = ""

        if reason is not None:
            reason = reason
            try:
                await member.ban(reason=reason)
            except:
                user = await commands.converter.UserConverter().convert(ctx, user)
                banneduser = await client.fetch_user(user.id)
                await ctx.guild.ban(banneduser, reason=reason)
```

It does not look possible, as if i used UserConverter it wouldn't ban members inside the server, if i used Members it wouldn't ban people outside the server. How can I do both?

Comment: you should add support for user ids

Comment: I do support IDs already, for members, and users (people not in the server already), I use `ctx.guild.ban` to ban  them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use use [`typing-union`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html#typing-union) which allows for the command to take in any of the specific types instead of a singular type..

Here is a simple example to send the name to verify it is working for both.

```py
import typing

@bot.command()
async def union(ctx, member: typing.Union[discord.Member, discord.User]):
    await ctx.send(member.name)
```